# Can we add baseline to SHAP?

Tags: shap, explainable-ai

I have a doubt. I am currently using an integrated gradient for the DNN model for explainability. In that, we can specify the baseline as a parameter to the function. I am using all zeros for this. I am using [alibi](https://github.com/SeldonIO/alibi/blob/master/doc/source/methods/IntegratedGradients.ipynb) library for this.

When coming to the non-differentiable models, I am using Shapley values in the [shap](https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library. I understand that Shapley works by taking a subset of the features. Can we add a baseline similar to the IG to the Shapley? In other words, feature less model, all zeros. And see how the model performs on that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. If say you are using `shap.KernelExplainer` then it takes an `data` argument at initialization. You can just make this a numpy array with all zeros to use that as the background sample.

Comment: Nice thought. Will look into it. Is it possible to do this for `shap.TreeExaplainer` because I am using xgboost?